# Can I create a package without a preexisting source file?

Tags: linux, redhat, rpm

As I understand it, the purpose of the Source: header in an rpm spec file is to specify a file (often a tar archive) that is used as the package payload.  This source file is typically generated beforehand, perhaps by make, and then rpmbuild is executed afterwards.

I'm wondering if it's possible to cut make out of the picture and just use rpmbuild.  Can the source file be created as part of the rpmbuild process itself, perhaps in the %build or %install step in the spec file?

If so, what does one use as the Source: header?  I can't just leave it blank, because rpmbuild complains.  Is there a way to tell rpm that the payload file is generated from within the spec file, and not supplied externally?

I don't want to create the source file separately because that would mean keeping track of the package name and version number in two places: in the rpm spec file, and also in whatever makefile or other script creates the payload file.  It seems like I should be able to do everything from within the spec file.

Comment: It is not true that you need to track the version in two places. You can use macros to read the name of the source and use that as version/name

Answer (score 0):

You want to call

```
%setup -q -c -T
```

see [1]. Example:

```
Name:           test
Version:        1
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        Test
License:        ...

%description
Test

%prep
%setup -q -c -T

%build
echo "int main() { return 0; } " > test.cpp
gcc -o test test.cpp

%install
install -Dpm 0755 test %{buildroot}%{_bindir}/test

%files
%{_bindir}/test

%changelog
...
```

[1] http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-specref-macros.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the a similar problem recently.  I ended up writing a script that read the spec file and did all the work.  We no longer had to manage Makefiles and spec files and whatever other ways some of our developers were managing this.

The script is publicly posted on github at:
https://github.com/alexnelsone/jenkins-rpm-build/blob/master/README.md.

It parses the info out of the spec file and then does all the work for you.